# Activity stops receiving Gyroscope sensor values after a period of time

Tags: android, android-sensors

Haven't found an answer to this.
I'm working on an app where I have to plot Accelerometer and Gyroscope values real-time in two separate activities. The accelerometer works just fine but in the gyroscope activity after a random period of time (ranging from 1 to 10 seconds approximately) the values stop coming and hence the plotting also stops.
This is the sensorChanged code.

```
public SensorEventListener gyroListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int acc) { }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        seriesx.appendData(new DataPoint(Lastx++,x),true,50);
        seriesy.appendData(new DataPoint(Lastx++,y),true,50);
        }
};
```

EDIT: Registering and Un-Registering the Sensor:

```
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(gyroListener, sensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(gyroListener);
}
```

Comment: can you post where are you register and unregister the your sensor listener, above info is not enough to predict the problem.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: have you set your sensor manager for gysoscope like sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE); and also on sensorchanged method check like this if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {} it help to sort out your pblm.

Comment: Yes I have, but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the Gyroscope sensor in the smart-watch I was running the application on: Moto 360. 
I then tested the app on Huawei Watch and it worked perfectly fine.